# NGINX server is not working on local Ubuntu 22.04.0 LTS machine (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

Tags: php, nginx

NGINX server is not working.

[Unable to access the site [ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBo7h.png)

I tried everything in google.com on the first 4 pages.

I tried and info settings:

1. Completely reinstalled NGINX
   (sudo apt-get remove nginx)
   sudo rm -rf /etc/nginx/ /usr/sbin/nginx /usr/share/man/man1/nginx.1.gz
   sudo apt-get --purge autoremove nginx && sudo dpkg --purge nginx
   sudo apt-get -o DPkg::options::=--force-confmiss --reinstall install nginx);
2. Changed ufw status [currently status:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK7XC.png);
3. Changed the etc/nginx/sites-available/default file several times [It looks like this now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzA6v.png),;
4. Status nginx: [looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iXFb.png);
5. PHP Version: 8.1.2| Version php-fpm8.1

I used to set up a NGINX server about 4-5 months ago and everything was fine. Now when I tried to start it, it started to give 40* and 50* some error, I don't remember, after trying to change settings - now it doesn't respond at all.

Please help, I will send any additional information.

Thank you.

Comment: And what are the error messages exactly that you get when starting `nginx`? If you are using default nginx install in ubuntu it should be `sudo systemctl status nginx` to show status and some latest logs. Also you should attach fpm status/logs `sudo systemctl status php-fpm`

Comment: sudo systemctl status nginx 
ноя 07 14:59:53 allidar systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
ноя 07 14:59:53 allidar systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
ноя 07 15:13:26 allidar systemd[1]: Stopping A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
ноя 07 15:13:26 allidar systemd[1]: nginx.service: Deactivated successfully.
ноя 07 15:13:26 allidar systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.

udo systemctl status php-fpm
Unit php-fpm.service could not be found.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will probably reinstall Ubuntu because I restarted my PC and now I have Google Chrome not opening, before that it was disabling BlueTooth, it's very all weird.